# pdf2htmlEX cannot save font to

Tags: windows, pdf-generation, pdf-to-html, pdf2htmlex

I have an error converting some pdf files, it is:

```
Internal Error: File Offset wrong for ttf table (name-data), -1 expected 174
Save Failed
Cannot save font to C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp//pdf2htmlEX-a14136/__tmp_font1.ttf
```

I'm using **Windows** last executable:

```
pdf2htmlEX version 0.14.6
Libraries:
poppler 0.33.0
libfontforge 20150621
cairo 1.12.18
Supported image format: png jpg svg
```

I'm testing it and fails at page 76 but if I change pages order, it still fails at page 76, even if I remove it from file.
It's fails even with command:
**pdf2htmlEx test.pdf**

And testing to split it into files of 10 pages for example, it works OK... but I can't use it, I need to convert full pdf.